# How to check what type/kind of cron I am using

Tags: linux, cron

I was reading the answer of this question
[Variables in crontab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639415/variables-in-crontab)

and it is written `In Vixie cron`. 
How can I check the cron name or type(I do not know how it is called) that i am using. I am on Debian 7.

thanks

Comment: On anything resembling a standard Linux, it's Vixie, or Vixie-compatible.

Comment: +1 while the question isn't very detailed, this is an interesting problem, and I would love to see even a rough sketch of how to solve it programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick check with `man cron` will tell you that Debian's `cron` is indeed Vixie cron.

Comment: But how would you solve that programmatically, say, from an install script?

Comment: Programmatically you can `grep` the man page: `man cron | grep -q Vixie && echo "Vixie cron indeed" || echo "some other kind of cron"`