# Cron xdotool doesn't run

Tags: shell, centos, cron, xdotool

I am new to using crontab, and I've been trying to get a simple cron job.
I want press F5 every 1 minute to refresh Mozzila Firefox. I am using xdotool for press F5.
I have script **/usr/local/bin/refresh.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash  
xdotool search --name "Mozilla Firefox" key F5
```

If i run it in command line it works fine. And permission:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 89 15. čec 10.32 refresh.sh
```

In **crontab** i have:

```
*/1 * * * * cd /usr/local/bin && sh refresh.sh
```

But script run by cron doesnt work.
Can anyone tell me what i do wrong?

Comment: Do you need to pass any `DISPLAY` variable? Do you have anything in the logs?

Comment: Yeah, i forgot place Display=: 0, thx you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`xdotool`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html) command is automation tool for X11 which allows you simulate keyboard/mouse input, but since crontab is run independently, it's required to define `DISPLAY` variable to specify which X Window System display server to use. Normally when you're login to the desktop this variable is assigned automatically, but crontab is running jobs in isolated environment (doesn't have even a tty associated), especially when you run commands via `root` account.

So in short, you should do define your job like:

```
*/1 * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /usr/local/bin/refresh.sh
```

Or you can define variables at the beginning of the file (in case of Vixie cron). See: [Variables in crontab?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639415/55075)

Also make sure the user which is running the job has granted access to the selected X display. If you need to grant the access, you need to assign the permission via `xhost` and `setfacl` commands and specify extra `XAUTHORITY` variable, see: [Xdotool using “DISPLAY=:0”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68054/21471) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

So I tried a bunch of things, but for some reason on Ubuntu 18.04 `echo $display` returned `:1` not `:0`. Also the only environment variable setter that seemed to work was adding:

```
export DISPLAY=":1"
```

directly to the script that cron is running.

Answer (score 2):

First as Parth said, make sure to type echo $DISPLAY on a terminal and get the output (for me it was :10.0 for some reason). Then inside the script that you are calling from cron, before you call xdotool, write the following:

```
export DISPLAY=:10.0 

#instead of :10.0 write your own output from before

export XAUTHORITY=/root/.Xauthority  

#if you are not a root user, instead of /root/.Xauthority write ~/.Xauthority
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/refresh.sh
```

`cd /usr/local/bin` is not necessary here as you're not running the cron job in `/usr/local/bin`

You need `cd` in below scenario

```
*/1 * * * * cd /usr/local/bin && ls >/var/somelog # wish to execute ls in a particular directory
```

Comment: you have right, i have "test.log" in "/usr/local/bin" for output of refresh.sh

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 23.04

I wanted to run `xdotool get_desktop` and was getting Error: `Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified, Can't open display: (null)`

Instead of just getting the `DISPLAY`, I also needed to get the `XAUTHORITY` (it was NOT `/root/.Xauthority`)

```
echo $DISPLAY
echo $XAUTHORITY
```

The fix was

```
export DISPLAY=<what you got from the $DISPLAY> && export XAUTHORITY=<what you got from @XAUTHORITY> && xdotool get_desktop
```

Example:

```
export DISPLAY=:0 && export XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.LYZR61 && xdotool get_desktop
```

Answer (score -1):

If someone wants to schedule xdotool commands with different tool, It is possible with At command (see [the tutorial](https://linuxize.com/post/at-command-in-linux/)). So, in order to work, you must define the environment variable DISPLAY (as explained by Kenorb). I first got the current value from that variable (echo $DISPLAY) in order to set in my script file (export DISPLAY=:0). Then, it can be ran like:

```
at xx:xx -f your_shell_script_file
```