# Trying to to run xdotool but getting 'Can't open display: (null)'

Tags: linux, macos, devops, xdotool

I am sorry to reporting this well known error message again.

Nothing works for me. I am running on MacOS Catalina, if it is important.

I installed `xdotool` with `brew` on my Mac and try to run

```
xdotool getmouselocation
```

The error message that follows is

```
Error: Can't open display: (null)
Failed creating new xdo instance
```

I was searching for a solution for a long time, found plenty of answers that said. Run `export DISPLAY=:0` and everything is fine. But this didn't work for me.

PS: For better understanding: What does DISPLAY means exactly? It is the monitor of my computer?

Comment: `xdotool` is an automation tool for the X11 window system. macOS doesn't use X11 - although it can be installed, it is unlikely to give the results you are looking for. This seems like an XY problem - what exactly is the issue you're trying to solve with xdotool?

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System), specifically the "Key Terms" section for a good description of what `DISPLAY` is in X11

Comment: Did you figure out a way?

Comment: I had a similar issue on ubuntu 23.04, this solved it https://stackoverflow.com/a/76571502/11333559

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [official notice by apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201341)

> X11 is no longer included with Mac, but X11 server and client libraries are available from the XQuartz project.

why X11 matters in this case ?

xdotool - command-line X11 automation tool.

So Alongside setting `export DISPLAY=:0`

install `xquartz`.

#### What does DISPLAY means exactly?

according [x manual](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/X.7.html#sect4)

> From the user's perspective, every X server has a display name of the form:
>
> ```
>                hostname:displaynumber.screennumber
> ```
>
> This information is used by the application to determine how it should
> connect to the server and which screen it should use by default (on
> displays with multiple monitors):
>
> 1. hostname
>    The hostname specifies the name of the machine to which the display is physically connected. If the hostname is not given, the
>    most efficient way of communicating to a server on the same machine
>    will be used.
> 2. displaynumber
>    The phrase "display" is usually used to refer to collection of monitors that share a common keyboard and pointer (mouse, tablet,
>    etc.). Most workstations tend to only have one keyboard, and
>    therefore, only one display. Larger, multi-user systems, however,
>    frequently have several displays so that more than one person can be
>    doing graphics work at once. To avoid confusion, each display on a
>    machine is assigned a display number (beginning at 0) when the X
>    server for that display is started. The display number must always be
>    given in a display name.
> 3. screennumber
>    Some displays share a single keyboard and pointer among two or more monitors. Since each monitor has its own set of windows, each
>    screen is assigned a screen number (beginning at 0) when the X server
>    for that display is started. If the screen number is not given, screen
>    0 will be used.

there is simpler description found [here](https://gerardnico.com/ssh/x11/display)

A display consists (simplified) of:

- a keyboard
- a mouse
- a screen

i.e. when you connect over ssh you are using different sets of these 3.