# Concatenating variables in crontab won't work

Tags: bash, cron

I have a very long (and messy) crontab (on my Mac). So I started cleaning it up by introducing variables for instance. Then I realized that concatenating variables (just like in a Bash script) does not work in my crontab. This is what I have:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
HOME=/Users/leuchtturm
# [1] Previously had this, but this does not seem to work
# $HOME is not being evaluated? Why?
# 
# VIRTUALENV_PYTHON=$HOME/.virtualenvs/py361/bin/python
# Now I have this (elaborated)
VIRTUALENV_PYTHON=/Users/leuchtturm/.virtualenvs/py361/bin/python

# the crontab entry
# Here $HOME is being expanded, but not in the example above [1]
#
*/2  *  *  *  *   source $HOME/.config_vars && $VIRTUALENV_PYTHON $HOME/workspace/monitoring/check_server.py
```

So in this line
`VIRTUALENV_PYTHON=$HOME/.virtualenvs/py361/bin/python` the variable `$HOME` is not being evaluated. My cron log has an entry that says "path not found".

Can someone enlighten me? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within *crontab* files, lines that look like `VAR=value` are definitions recognized by *cron* and not executed under a *shell*. So the value of a variable definition is not expanded in any way.

On the other hand, the *command* in a *crontab entry*, gets executed by the default *crontab* shell or, in your case, by the shell defined with the `SHELL`variable.

Beware also that particular *cron* versions may not let you define arbitrary variables, but only particular ones like `SHELL`, `HOME`, `MAILTO`, etc. See [Variables in crontab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639415/variables-in-crontab).

Comment: So is my approach basically wrong? Should I put the details and the path setting into a bash script and call that script from within the cronjob instead of setting the path in the crontab etc? And if so: Where should that script reside? In my Python project folder?

Comment: Particular *cron* versions may not let you define variables, but I think that most will. So use your approach of defining variables to make the *crontab* entries clearer. Only, do not use a variable to define (part of) another...

Comment: Also, for what it may be worth, I usually define a *bash* (shell) script to invoke a program from *crontab*. At the head of the script I define variables as I need to and then invoke the program (in your case Python). That gives you a place to prepare files, clean them and so on.