# Cron Job with PHP and an increment variable argument

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I would like to know of it is possible to execute a Cron job every 30 seconds and increment an argument from a value (1 for exemple) to another (50000) :
Like :

```
wget https://mon-url.com/file/cron.php?id=1 >/dev/null 2>&1 
wget https://mon-url.com/file/cron.php?id=2 >/dev/null 2>&1 
wget https://mon-url.com/file/cron.php?id=3 >/dev/null 2>&1 
wget https://mon-url.com/file/cron.php?id=4 >/dev/null 2>&1 
....
wget https://mon-url.com/file/cron.php?id=50000 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Is there any command to do that programaticaly ? 
Thanks

Comment: It does not really have to do something with PHP, something you might be looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639415/variables-in-crontab You could also write a shell script doing the `wget` and storing the value somewhere which is executed by cron.

Comment: You could potentially store this increment in a database and request and update it everytime it's called again if you just wanted a typical +1.

Comment: @ConorReid It's an brillant idea ! Thanks

Comment: That’s a lot of queries just to iterate over a simple loop. Single bash script would do much better.

Comment: @Mike any lead to help me with your bash script ?

Comment: My bash script? :) Simple loop will do, there are lots of examples on the net and SO. Just make sure you create some sort of a PID file to prevent the script of running twice or more should it be run too quickly.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested before i'd rather go with bash script like this (or similar):

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1;
while [ $i -le 5 ]
do
    wget https://mon-url.com/file/cron.php?id=$i >/dev/null 2>&1
    i=$(($i+1));
    sleep 30
done
```

Regards.
Ps. change 5 after -le to whathever you need

Comment: You can also do `((i++))` to increment btw.

Answer (score 0):

Look here below you want:

```
$x = 1; // You value set to minim
$y = 50000; // Your value set to maxim

while($x <= $y) {
  echo "wget https://mon-url.com/file/cron.php?id=$x  >/dev/null 2>&1";
  $x++;
}
```

You can use this in your script for cron jobs. Good look!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps u can just `export` your counter incrementing it by one every time

```
COUNTER=0
*/30 * * * * wget https://mon-url.com/file/cron.php?id="$COUNTER" >/dev/null 2>&1 && export COUNTER=$((COUNTER+1))
```